# is it possible to use iis 7 to manage users when using forms authentication with asp.net

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, forms-authentication, user-management

I have an ASP.NET web application that is using forms authentication. Everything is configured and working correctly.  However, i'm dealing with the issue of creating and maintaining users and role membership.

I know that I can roll my own solution but I'm wondering if there is an alternative solution?

Does iis7 provide screens for managing forms authentication users?
Is there a reliable, free solution that someone would recommend?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been unable to find anything with IIS7 that would allow management of forms-authentication users.

However, I have found the following alternatives...

WinForm: http://sourceforge.net/projects/aspnetdb/

WebBased: http://www.asp.net/Learn/Security/tutorial-12-cs.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution, but a temporary workaround...

In Visual Studio there is Website -> "ASP.NET Configuration" menu item that will start a little administration app where you can manage users and roles.  However, this is very rudimentary, and VERY slow.

I don't know how much time you had, but the framework for FormsAuthentication is good and you would only need to create a few forms to "roll your own".  I've actually been thinking about making something like this for a long time, but usually the built in Configuration utility is enough, or the CMS' we work with have their own authentication management modules.

Comment: the problem is that the customer needs to manage users and the visual studio admin app won't be available.

Answer (score 0):

With Asp.Net MVC, you can try the [mvcmembership starter kit](http://mvcmembership.codeplex.com/).

What would be really cool if someone implemented all this into a [Portable Area](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/hex/archive/2009/11/01/asp-net-mvc-portable-areas-via-mvccontrib.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

http://mywsat.codeplex.com/

See also these related questions:

[User management in Silverlight, create custom UI or use ASP.NET website administration tool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058302/)

[How do I manage ASP.Net users on a non development server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500959/)