# How do I manage ASP.Net users on a non development server?

Tags: asp.net, user-management

In Visual Studio 2010 there is a handy tool for managing users for my Silverlight Business Application.  How do I do this with my deployed application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to say, but you will have to write user management code in your app.

You might find this article interesting.

https://web.archive.org/web/20210306174425/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/052307-1.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Good question, I'm surprised there isn't a built-in, pre-canned solution  :)

There's an option here: http://mywsat.codeplex.com/

Related questions:

[is it possible to use iis 7 to manage users when using forms authentication with asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2494497/)

[User management in Silverlight, create custom UI or use ASP.NET website administration tool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058302/)